# ¿Es posible colocar un iframe de revés?

Tags: html

Necesito hacer que un `iframe` este de revés. El en el `iframe` tengo un vídeo al revés así que para que se vea correctamente en la página debo invertir la imagen:

```
<center>
    <iframe scrolling="auto" width="660px" height="500px" class="flipH" src="http://192.168.2.1:8080/stream_simple.html"></iframe>
</center>
```

Comment: @Sr1871 ¿Porqué no considerar tu comentario como respuesta?

Comment: Funciona pero el problema es que el iframe deja de estar centrado. EDIT: Vale, es porque en tu respuesta has quitado el <center>. Solucionado.

Comment: Si estás haciendo tu página usando `doctype` `HTML5`, evita la etiqueta `center` ya que no es compatible con este estándar (aunque pueda funcionar en algunos browsers). Esta etiqueta ha quedado obsoleta y la recomendación general es intentar evitarla.

Comment: ¿cuando dices que quieres invertir las imágenes te refieres a un giro de 180 grados en el eje X o Y o a invertir la imagen como en un espejo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```html
<center><iframe scrolling="auto" width="660px" height="500px" class="flipH" style="transform: rotate(180deg);" src="http://192.168.2.1:8080/stream_simple.html"></iframe></center>
```

Con `style="transform: rotate(180deg);"` puedes rotarlo, también puedes añadirlo a tu clase que tienes en el iframe.

con css

```css
.flipH {
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<center><iframe scrolling="auto" width="660px" height="500px" class="flipH" src="http://192.168.2.1:8080/stream_simple.html"></iframe></center>
```

Comment: Sería bueno hacerlo con `CSS` y añadirle al menos los `prefixes` `-ms` y `-webkit` para soportar `ie9` y versiones un poco más antiguas de `webkit`.

Comment: @ElChiniNet lo he agregado, si algo esta mal decirme qué, para agregarlo/corregirlo-

Comment: Está perfecto, con esos dos prefixes es suficiente ;)